# Navigating back to fragment of an activity from another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, back

I am trying to navigate back to a fragment of an activity from another activity.  I have set

```
 getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

but whenever, I use the app back icon it always takes me to the first fragment of the activity rather than the fragment from which another activity was launched.  How can I achieve this.  I think I might have to implement

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the fragment you want to go back to manually to the backstack.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
YourFragmentName myFragment = new YourFragmentName();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment);

//if you with to add it to backStack, do this, otherwise skip the line below
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

hope no a  late answer might help someone later
you do this

---

**FragmentManager** fragmentManager = **getFragmentManager()**;
                                        fragmentManager.**beginTransaction().replace(R.id**.(the i of the layout of you current acticity),**new** (name of your activity))**.commit()**;